# MySQL Join for newsletters

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a problem with mysql query. I am sending newsletters.

My mysql schema looks like to follwing http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/178b7/18

How am I suppose to get from the database the COUNT of the mails that will be send.

For every List_ID in LISTS TAKE every base_id from lists_mailbases, and then count all of the base_id that are in email_database.

For example in my schema list1 should have 4 recipients, list 2 should have 2 recipients.

I wrote something like this:

```
SELECT l.id, COUNT(*) FROM lists l 
JOIN lists_mailbases lm ON l.id = lm.list_id 
JOIN email_database ed ON ed.base_id = lm.base_id 
GROUP BY l.id;
```

but as a result, I have almost twice more results i should have. (on sqlfiddle it is ok but in my main database where i have a lot of records it gives me wrong data)

Comment: I think you're trying to COUNT(DISTINCT ed.base_id) check my answer

Answer (score 1):

nice question with SQLFiddle!

just add ed.base_id to your GROUP BY

```
  SELECT l.id,ed.base_id, COUNT(*) , GROUP_CONCAT(ed.email)
  FROM lists l JOIN lists_mailbases lm ON l.id = lm.list_id 
  JOIN email_database ed ON ed.base_id = lm.base_id
  GROUP BY l.id,ed.base_id;
```

your `lists_mailbases` has repeated data by the way, it has 2 rows with the same base_id.

if your data is correct and you want to count DISTINCT base_id, just do `COUNT(DISTINCT base_id)`
like below

```
SELECT l.id, COUNT(DISTINCT ed.base_id) , GROUP_CONCAT(ed.email)
   FROM lists l JOIN lists_mailbases lm ON l.id = lm.list_id 
   JOIN email_database ed ON ed.base_id = lm.base_id
GROUP BY l.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you are getting twice as much as you expect, it looks like one of the joins produces more than one record for the join. Diagnose that out.

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(*)
FROM
(
   SELECT l.id, ED.BASE_ID FROM lists l 
   JOIN lists_mailbases lm ON l.id = lm.list_id 
   JOIN email_database ed ON ed.base_id = lm.base_id 
   GROUP BY l.id, ED.BASE_ID
) A;
```